# computed property that changes its value with action in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller

I do have a controller that has an action {{loadRight}} that passes  the current model to the controller when I click a button.

When I first load the app, I also use firstElement computed property which pulls the first element from my model array.

Basically what I want to do is create a second computed property which would return the current model that's clicked so that I can use this information in my template.

I created a currentElement computed property however since I suck at javascript I couldn't pass the current model from action method to the computed property. I keep getting model is not defined error.

I would appreciate any help. Below is my controller.

```
// controller works.js
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstElement: function () {
    return this.get('model.firstObject');
  }.property('model.[]'),


  currentElement: function () {
    if(!currentModel) {
      currentModel = this.get('model.firstObject');
    }
    return currentModel;
  }.property('model.[]'),


  actions: {
    loadRight: function (currentElement) {
    console.log(currentElement);
    }

  }});
```

Comment: to simplify things I just created a gist: https://gist.github.com/ilteris/ffe5064a3c2242dbbcd5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define property `selectedElement` (that's clicked). When `loadRight` fired you could set `selectedElement` with `selection`.
Then `currentElement` is simple computed property, depends on `model.firstObject` and `selectedElement`.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstElement: function () {
    return this.get('model.firstObject');
  }.property('model.[]'),

  selectedElement: null,

  currentElement: function () {
    return (this.get('selectedElement') || this.get(`firstElement`));
  }.property('firstElement', 'selectedElement'),

  actions: {
    loadRight: function (selection) {
      this.set('selectedElement', selection);
      return false; // or something transition logic 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: When the app starts currentElement is empty (before any click). I would like to set currentElement to model.firstObject here. So if(!selectedElement)     I have to return  this.get('model.firstObject').

Comment: fixed `currentElement`

Comment: interesting, what does .property('firstElement','selectedElement') do?

Comment: computed property based on many others: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: Thank you. I think my last question would be where do I set the selectedElement with selection. in the hbs? here's my current hbs.

Comment: in `loadRight` action. `this.set('selectedElement', selection);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80578/discussion-between-ilteris-and-artych).